# Duplicate menu item when app crash on home screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

Well, i used App Compact Actionbar with ActionBarActivity.
when app crash, app will restart again and i got duplicate menu item on App Home Screen .
i don't know why its crash.
Can anybody please answer my.
i hope i'll get the result.

Here is Optionmenu XML.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.demo.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_cart"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_cart_hover"
    android:title="@string/action_cart"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/item_actionbar_cart_count"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your logcat here.!?

Comment: Actually in logcat i didn't see anything related to option menu error.
in logcat there is only things related to app crash(Other issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what happened when your apps crashing (a `logcat` will be helpful), but try to call `clear` method :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear(); //call the clear method
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.signin, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: @BT At least wait till OP post Logcat....How did you know your answer solve ops issue?

Comment: @MD i can update my answer :) And putting the clear might solve the issue, why not?

Comment: @BT But this is not a absolute answer so please put some comment first for verification and then post an answer.....

Comment: @MD Sorry, i feel like this can be an answer, do you think all of your answer is absolute? :) And i've said im ready to update the answer. Btw, we did things our way, i dont want we chat here, in someone's question LOL

Comment: @BT Actually we always posted an answers based on Logcat or issue not based on question...So, next time be careful.....

Comment: @MD yes i see..sorry man, my brain a little full earlier...own code + SO LOL, so sometimes just try to answer what "might" be the answer. Thanks for your comments